# What information is gained when just one single half of an entangled photon pair is detected, following its transmission through a polarizer?

Tags: photons, quantum-entanglement, polarization, information

My admittedly limited understanding of QM is that it is a matter of probabilities whether or not a photon is (re)transmitted through a polarising filter and that these are a function of the relative orientation of the polarization of the photon and that of the filter. Unfortunately, a single detection event cannot distinguish a very likely from a very unlikely one. Since the same applies to a case in which the photon is absorbed, it seems that not much information, if any, can be gained, when what would be nice is that we could learn something about the polarisation of the photon for example. Even if statistics are collected on streams of successive photons, they're likely each to be oriented differently in relation to the filter, so not much information can be gained by examining the statistics either.

Comment: I’m not exactly sure of what you are asking. The information you gain from observing one of the entangled photons gives you information about the other one. That allows you to make a precise prediction about a similar measurement on that other one.

Comment: It is, of course, believed that the information you gain from observing one of the entangled photons gives you information about the other one, but my question is about what information you gain in the first instance. I take it that the only information gained is that the polarization of the photon exiting the polarizer is obviously aligned with the angle the polarizing filter makes with the laboratory. Or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Since the photon was in a superposition prior to its encounter with the polarizer, there was no specific information to gain.